# How to tell if iOS Today Widget is being updated in the background?

Tags: ios, ios9, today-extension

I have an iOS Today Widget that makes an expensive API call (expensive as in the more it is called, the more I pay money). If I implement widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler in my widget, then the widget can be updated in the background several times a day without the user ever looking at their Notification Center.

In an app, there is a key-value-pair in the options dictionary of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions that tells you if the app is launching the background or not, but there isn't anything similar in a widget that I can find. There is also the call to get the applicationState in UIApplication, which also isn't available in a widget.

So, is there any *reliable* way in my widget to know that the system is updating my widget in the background and the user isn't looking at their Notification Center to save myself from unnecessary API calls? I'm fine with the content not being completely up to date when the user does look at the widget because I can update it pretty quickly after it loads.

I've been trying to find a hacky solution like something different with the view or window that is different when the widget is being updated in the background, but haven't found anything yet. I've noticed the occasionally when the widget is initialized in the background that the window frame has a height of zero, but that doesn't seem to always be the case.

I'm also aware that if I don't implement widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler, then my widget isn't updated in the background which is a possible solution, but I'm looking for a way that I can have my cake and eat it too.

If anyone has any other ideas, I'm all ears. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed an Apple Developer Technical Support ticket on this. They responded and told me that this was not possible that that I would need to file an enhancement request for this. I filed rdar://27434852.

Answer (score 2):

If you just plan on debugging and understand how often it is being called, you could use some logging on the device (possibly even trigger some kind of analytics event informing every time `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` is called, in order to mediate whether that is happening too often).

An example of an active solution to decrease the number of requests is to timegate the requests where, if `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` runs more than once every *x* minutes/hours/etc you would not call the API but simply call the `completionBlock` with no new data.

A final example with even more rigorous limit on the API calls could be to avoid them at all on the Today's extension (just like you said). This means the API calls would only be done when the actual app is launched, and the response persisted (you can have a shared container between the app and the Today's extension - just a folder or even something more complex like a sqlite store for Core Data) and always retrieve the data from the shared container to update the Today's extension UI.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I want to make sure that the API is called immediately when the user opens the notification center and sees the widget. So time gating and only updating in the app wouldn't be sufficient workarounds.

Comment: What about making the call only when `viewDidLoad` of the widget being shown is called? Being an expensive call and also possibly being in a slow network can mean there's a slight delay between the request and the response, but this would make sure the request is made if the extension is being drawn from a user's action, rather than a background trigger.

Comment: viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, et al are called even when it's updated in the background, presumably because it is snapshotting the final view. And widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler is called in both cases as well. Hence my inability to tell if the widget is being run in the background or not.

Comment: The view lifecycle calls are not called when your widget isn't on screen. Not sure what you mean by "even when it's updated in the background"

Comment: They are indeed called when your widget is not on screen. I put in log messages for every call and sure enough those show up even when the phone is locked, the screen is off when a widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler is fired off from the system in the background.

Answer (score 0):

`widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` is actually pretty unreliable in iOS 9. If you just kick off your network call in the background from `viewDidLoad`, it will only be called when your today widget comes on screen.

Comment: It's not reliable as in you never know when it's going to be kicked off in the background, but it does seem to run often in my tests, sometimes more than once an hour. And when it is run in the background, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear are all run. So doing something in viewDidLoad will be run when the widget is in the background, unfortunately.

Comment: It's not reliable as in it doesn't always get called even in the foreground. It's been a while since I tested this, but I don't think you'll get any lifecycle calls in the background if you don't implement `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`

Comment: Right, I agree that the widget is never awoken in the background if you don't implement widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler. This is one of the few things Apple documented properly about this call. The disadvantage to not implementing this call is that the widget can take longer to appear when the Notification Center is opened when it isn't suspended in memory and needs to be initialized from scratch. Implementing widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler generally results in the widget often hanging out in memory which then makes it quicker to appear. So I was hoping to keep it.

Comment: Ah I took it from your comment `I'm fine with the content not being completely up to date when the user does look at the widget because I can update it pretty quickly after it loads` that it wasn't a big deal. I was not aware that implementing `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` had any effect on the system keeping your widget around in memory.